# TinyMCE editor.getContent does not return mark-tag

Tags: tinymce

I made a plugin that adds the mark-tags to the selected text.

`<p><mark title="mark1">MyText</mark></p>`

when I select the text again to change or unmark only the text is selected but not the mark-tag (when there is a leading p-tag).

How do i get tinyMCE to select the mark-tag?
Is there a way to get the position of the selection so i can scan the content for this tags myself?

(I Need this tag for special purposes and do not need a other solution to color my text)

Comment: have you add this tag to the valid_elements or extended valid_elements in your tinymce config?

Comment: found a solution - see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fond my solution. It works perfect

> //Getting the seleted node
>
> tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().outerHTML;
>
> //remove the entire tag
> tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.remove(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.getParent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(),
> 'mark'));
>
> //create a new tag at the selection-point
> tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.create('mark',
> {title : 'MyTitle'} , 'MyText');